# React useEffect executing last function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I need to have 2 different functions that update 2 different components only once in the beginning. Hence, I'm using `useEffect`. The code is as follows

```
const loadCategories = () => {
    getCategories().then((c) => setValues({ ...values, categories: c.data }));
}

const loadStores = () => {
    getStores().then((c) => setValues({ ...values, stores: c.data }));
}

useEffect(() => {
  loadStores();
  loadCategories();
}, []);
```

Both the functions are setting the values of the dropdown elements

The problem is though both functions are exectued, only `loadCategories()` function logic is reflected in the UI. How to make both functions logic reflect in the UI?

Comment: Is the `useEffect` function inside `loadStores`? It looks like you might have an infinite recursion?

Comment: No, it's outside the `loadStores`. The 2 `load` functions are outside the `useEffect`

Comment: Only reason which I can conclude is that, `loadCategories()` override `loadStores()` but that is not case cause first set state in `categories` and second set state in `stores`.

Can you try to run only, first function `loadStories()` and to check does that function alone update UI at all. Maybe the problem is in it, or when applying it on UI.

Comment: @PredragDavidovic When I use only one function inside the `useEffect`, it works fine, but when I use 2 functions one after the other, the last function will get reflected in the UI even though both functions ran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first better practice to add those function in useEffect or to wrap them in `useCallback` hook.
second both or your function are promises so each may not resolve at same time and when you trying to update state values will keep it initial value that why your first function is not reflecting in the ui instead use  `setState callback` to get the previous state like this :

```
useEffect(() => {
const loadCategories = () => {
    getCategories().then((c) => setValues(prevState=>({ ...prevState, categories: c.data })));
}

const loadStores = () => {
    getStores().then((c) => setValues(prevState=>({ ...prevState, stores: c.data })));
}
  loadStores();
  loadCategories();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wait for both promises to resolve and then use the data from both to update your state, combined in whatever way you see fit.

```
useEffect(() => {
    Promise.all([getCategories(), getStores()]).then(([categories, stores]) => {
      setValues({categories, stores})
    });
}, []);
```

The problem with what you had before (as you experienced) is that `values` is always the value at the point at which `useState` was run on this render.

If you really want to do the updates separately, than you can look into useReducer: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

Answer (score 1):

Promise and `useEffect` can be challenging as the component might dismount before you promise is full-filled.

Here is a solution which works quite well:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let isRunning = true;
  Promise.all([ 
    getCategories(),
    getStores()
  ]).then(([stores, categories]) => {
    // Stop if component was unmounted:
    if (!isRunning) { return }
    // Do anything you like with your lazy load values:
    console.log(stores, categories)
  });
  return () => {
    isRunning = false;
  }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are lying to React about dependencies. Both your functions depend on the `values` state variable. That's also why it does not work: When the hooks get run, `values` gets closured, then when `setValues` runs `values` changes (gets set to a new object), however inside the closure it is still referencing the old values.

You can easily resolve that by passing a callback to `setValues`, this way you do not have a dependency to the outside and the values update is atomic:

```
 setValues(values => ({ ...values, stores: c.data }));
```

Comment: This worked. I can only accept one answer. Hence, I have upvoted